# Problema con una suma SQL con Android y SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo un problema con una suma de datos en SQLite en Android. Me devuelve valores enteros sin contar con los decimales.

El código del MainActivity es:

```
       PTotal = findViewById(R.id.tv_precio2);

       double  ptotal = helper.Total();
       PTotal.setText(String.valueOf(ptotal));
```

Y el código de dbhelper es:

```
    public float Total(){
        int total = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery( "SELECT SUM(Precio) as Total FROM tabel_notes", null) ;
       
        if (cur.moveToFirst())
        {
         int totals = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("Total"));
            return totals;
        }
       while (cur.moveToNext());
        return Total();
    }
```

El código para crear la tabla es:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ suma + "(" + row_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + row_title + " TEXT," + row_note + " TEXT, "+ row_precio + " TEXT," + row_created + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

El valor que obtengo después de sumar la columna `row_precio` siempre es entero, si uso `double` o `float` sale `*.0`, siempre con `0` en la parte decimal.

Parece que solo toma la parte entera y los decimales no los toma en cuenta. Si creo la columna con `DECIMAL` o `INTEGER` resulta igual. Si quiero sumar `12.1 + 11.2` me da como valor `23.0` y no `23.3`.

Comment: Mira la respuesta que te han dado, a´hi tienes la solución, devuelves el resultado en un int, no puedes devolver decimales en un entero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema en esta línea:

```
int totals = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("Total"));
```

Estás obteniendo la suma total como un número entero y almacenando el resultado en una variable entera.

Debes usar en su lugar [`Cursor.getFloat(int columnIndex)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getFloat(int)):

```
float totals = cur.getFloat(cur.getColumnIndex("Total"));
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono,